# ECS, how to add user-data after creating ecs instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

I can't find a way to specify a user-data after creating ECS instance definition.

Document says `You can pass this user data into the Amazon EC2 launch wizard in Step 6.g of Launching an Amazon ECS Container Instance.`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/bootstrap_container_instance.html#multi-part_user_data

ECS is launched automatically, how do you specify the user data?

I want to send `/var/log/syslog` to cloudwatch and I need to add `user data` (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_cloudwatch_logs.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to add the user data as a autoscaling group property

steps are

> 1. copy existing launch configuration
> 2. edit user data of the launch configuration
> 3. edit autoscaling group to use the created launch configuration
> 4. terminate ecs instances so that the modified autoscaling group launches new ec2 with new launch configuration

Answer (score 2):

via terraform we can pass it as template file within launch config

```
data "template_file" "user_data" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/templates/user_data.sh")}"

  vars = {
    ecs_config        = "${var.ecs_config}"
    ecs_logging       = "${var.ecs_logging}"
    cluster_name      = "${var.cluster}"
    env_name          = "${var.environment}"
    custom_userdata   = "${var.custom_userdata}"
    cloudwatch_prefix = "${var.cloudwatch_prefix}"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, user data scripts and cloud-init directives run only during the first boot cycle when an EC2 instance is launched.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/execute-user-data-ec2/

In the article it also explain further possible workaround.