# ECS - User Data For EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, autoscaling, user-data

I am trying to create a docker image based on httpd with a custom information about the docker image. So for that am trying to set the ECS_ENABLE_CONTAINER_METADATA=true in /etc/ecs/ecs.config.

I am trying to do it in the user data of the ecs instance. First thing i noticed is there is no provision to specify the user data while creating  the cluster.

Then tried copying the launch configuration and edited the user data per below stackoverflow,

[ECS, how to add user-data after creating ecs instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59126603/ecs-how-to-add-user-data-after-creating-ecs-instance)

But when i try to run tasks, I found that no ecs instance is linked with the cluster.

Any suggestions if you had run to similar issue ?

Comment: Can you show your user data?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the ECS instance is not registered with the cluster. You need to ensure that the AMIs you use to create the ECS instance has the ECS agent enabled and running. The full list of AMIs is available in the ECS developer docs under container instances.